# Magento Cart: Show Discount excl. tax instead incl tax

Tags: cart, tax, discount, ce-1.9.2.4, taxes

We added discount rules in our cart.
Our problem: We need to show the Discount excl. tax instead of incl. tax.
Has anyone an idea how to do this? It should be shown in all cases. Such as cart, pdfs, emails and so on...

I added this as a bug or request to Magento.
https://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/1465

Greets 
Sven

Comment: What's your setting in Configuration > Tax > Apply discount on price (including tax is calculated based on store tax, if "Apply Tax after Discount" is selected.)?

Comment: Customer tax: **After Discount**.
Apply Discount on Prices: **Including Taxes**.